# Why doesn't python send output to stdout?

Tags: python, output, stdout, python-3.5

Here's a minimum working example (MWE), saved as `mwe.py`:

```
import sys

def f(n):
    print("Testing print()...")
    sys.stdout.write("Calculating f({})...".format(n))
```

When run from the command line I get no output whatsoever:

```
username@hostname:~/mydir$ python mwe.py 'f(99)'
username@hostname:~/mydir$
```

When run from within `python`
I get output (some info removed):

```
username@hostname:~/mydir$ python
Python 3.5.4 (default, DATE, HH:MM:SS)
[GCC X.X.X Compatible Apple LLVM X.X.X (clang-X.X.X)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mwe import f
>>> f(99)
Testing print()...
Calculating f(99)...
>>>
```

Why do these output statements work within `python` but *not* from the command line?

Comment: When you run `python mwe.py 'f(99)'` you're passing `f(99)` as an argument to Python.  The argument is not executed against the source file.  Only the source file is executed and it never calls the function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvotes and vote to close? Question asked, question answered. What's being asked is clear from context. Sure, it's a minor error that was easily fixed, but I'm sure I'm not the only Python user who has or will ever experience this problem. For that reason alone, it's probably worthwhile to retain the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`python mwe.py 'f(99)'` doesn't mean "run the `f` function from `mwe.py` with argument `99`". If you wanted to do that from the command line, you could execute

```
python -c 'import mwe; mwe.f(99)'
```

`python mwe.py 'f(99)'` means "run the script `mwe.py` with `sys.argv[1]` set to the string `"f(99)"`". The script `mwe.py` doesn't examine `sys.argv` or print anything at all; it just defines a function and ends.

Answer (score 1):

This: `python mwe.py 'f(99)'` just shouldn't work. In this case, `'f(99)'` is just passed as an argument to the program.

Try using `python -c 'import mwe; mwe.f(99)` instead. (also read more about command line usage of python by typing `python -h`)